# TCPDF V5.0.002 line 3018 -> Trying to access array offset of type null. How to fix it?

Tags: php, pdf

I am currently working with TCPDF (https://tcpdf.org) to help me generate PDF files. I recently upgraded to PHP V 7.4, and this Specific line of code is giving my the error: **trying to access array offset of type null**

```
$this->SetFont($this->footer_font[0], $this->footer_font[1], $this->footer_font[2]);
```

Please note that this is most likely a compatibility issue since the I did not change anything in my code.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that PHP7.4 will generate a notice if you use non array value as array.

**[Array-style access of non-arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.core.non-array-access)**

> Trying to use values of type null, bool, int, float or resource as an
> array (such as $null["key"]) will now generate a notice.

To fix your code, you should check `$this->footer_font` value and ensure it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($this->footer_font)){
    $this->SetFont($this->footer_font[0], $this->footer_font[1], $this->footer_font[2]);
            }
```

You can use it